# java -version different than expected

Tags: java, version

I'm having a problem with determining what version of java am I using:)
`cmd.exe` is using `java.exe` from `C:\WINDOWS\system32` as specified in `Path` environment variable.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java.exe -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

But in windows when I right-click on that file and select `Properties->Version->Full Version` it says `1.6.0_22-b04`.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

This means you have two installations. Check your `c:\program files\Java` folder. Also check your PATH environment variable - it should point to the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Change to a directory which **is not in your PATH environment variable** and run `java -version`. Note that the current directory always is the first entry in `PATH`.

Comment: Bingo.  It's invoking the one that resides in `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: @Mark, I hate it... This forced to write `which` for windows.

Comment: Yeah, the \*nix alternative where you have to manually do `./someBinary` is confusing at first ("why do I need to specify the directory if I'm already *in* it?") but avoids problems later.